# Not able to get JSON data from Plupload

Tags: php, jquery, json, plupload

I'm uploading files using Plupload and it works fine.

I've tested various suggestions found here on Stackoverflow, but I'm still not able to get any sensible data from my JSON respons.

In my `upload.php` file I have `echo json_encode($result);`

In my JS I do the following:

```
  uploader.bind('FileUploaded', function(up, file, response) {
    var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(response);
    var obj2 = eval(response);

    alert(response.toSource()); // <-- Outputs raw data
    alert(obj); // <-- is NULL
    alert(obj2.toSource()); // <-- Outputs eval data format
    alert(obj2.logo_url); // <-- Is not working
  });
```

The `alert(response.toSource());` returns this:

```
({response:"{
  \"logo_url\":\"http:\\/\\/mysite.com\\/uploads\\/3b\\/7b019482c806f9_logo.jpeg\",
  \"img_id\":\"30\",
  \"feedback\":{\"message\":\"File uploaded\",
  \"success\":true}}", 
  status:200})
```

and `obj` is NULL.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: firstly before anything else install something like FireBug and use console.log as alert cannot handle complex types i think - console.log will show all the objects contents

Comment: I'm already a frequent user of Firebug. Doing a console.log or alert will show the same result

Comment: it wont actually, alert will show "[object Object]" if its not null which doesn't tell you much, at least in Firefox. I just called parseJSON on that response string and it worked fine so it is odd that calling it on the object isnt working for you, good luck

Comment: In Firefox you can use `.toSource()` which is the same as `console.log`. So doing a `alert(obj.toSource());` gives me a js error because object is null. If I got "[object Object]" I would know that `parseJSON` worked. Now I think it's not working because `json_encode` ads slashes - causing `parseJSON` to fail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of things wrong

1. Remove the quote escaping \"
2. response + status should be in quotes

i.e.

```
{
    "response": {
        "logo_url": "http: \\/\\/mysite.com\\/uploads\\/3b\\/7b019482c806f9_logo.jpeg",
        "img_id": "30",
        "feedback": {
            "message": "Fileuploaded",
            "success": true
        }
    },
    "status": 200
}
```

Comment: How can I remove it? It's generated by `json_encode($result)`. `Status` is also added for some reason. I don't have this problems in my webservice file where all data is returned using `json_encode()`

Comment: what version of php are you using? if its less than 5.4.0 then you need to watch out for magic quotes (magic_quotes_gpc in php.ini). It would be best to fix it in the php but you could edit the json string in javascript before parsing it but thats the messy way. Make sure that whatever lib you are using doesnt have its own json_encode which is being used instead of the php one (its quite a new func and quite a lot of libs wrote their own possibly worse ones)

Comment: I found the answer. The JSON was valid. I tried to do `$.parseJSON(response)`, but the corect way is `$.parseJSON(response.response)`. That did the trick.

Comment: ahh shit i remember having the same problem :P good that you found it and it was something easy, when I parsed just the response body it was fine so I shoulda seen it was that. good that you got it sorted and thanks for accepting even though I didnt really answer the Q :P

Answer (score 3):

var uploader = $("#multi_upload").pluploadQueue();

```
uploader.bind('FileUploaded', function (up, file, res) {
    var res1 = res.response.replace('"{', '{').replace('}"', '}');
    var objResponse = JSON.parse(res1);
    alert(objResponse.fn);
});
```