# How to process backend coldfusion processing script response

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, coldfusion, plupload

I have implemented plupload using a ColdFusion backend script (available at https://gist.github.com/1116037).

The url attribute in the uploading page is url : '../upload.cfc?method=upload',
This simply calls a function within the cfc script. It works fine. This script also creates a variable called 'response' to hold information uploaded files.

The problem I am having is accessing the information held in the 'response' variable.
I would like to display that information in a table after the all the files have been uploaded to the server.

I am using the queue_widget for my needs’ think that an event (onComplete) needs to be triggered to call a function to process the information in variable, but I don't know how to do this.

I need to access the information held in the 'response' variable, preferably in ColdFusion code. Has anyone managed to get plupload working with ColdFusion yet?

Any help, guidance or coding would be appreciated.

Here is the full code I have used:

This is the main page - queue_widget.cfm

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" dir="ltr">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
<title>Plupload - Queue widget example</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../js/jquery.plupload.queue/css/jquery.plupload.queue.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../js/plupload.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../js/plupload.flash.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../js/jquery.plupload.queue/jquery.plupload.queue.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Queue widget example</h1>
  <p>Shows the jQuery Plupload Queue widget and under different runtimes.</p>
  <div style="float: left; margin-right: 20px">
  <h3>Flash runtime</h3>
    <div id="flash_uploader" style="width: 700px;">Your browser does not have Flash installed!</div>
  </div>  
  <br style="clear: both" />
<cfoutput><cfset mnum=6></cfoutput>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    // Setup flash version
$("#flash_uploader").pluploadQueue({
    // General settings
    runtimes : 'flash',
    url : '../upload.cfc?method=upload',
    max_file_size : '1mb',
    max_file_count: <cfoutput>#mnum#</cfoutput>, // You can limit the num of files that can be uploaded by manipulating the mnum variable above
    unique_names : false,
    multiple_queues : true,
    multi_selection: true,
    filters : [
        {title : "Image files", extensions : "jpg,gif,png"}
    ],
    init : {
        FilesAdded: function(up, files) {
            plupload.each(files, function(file) {
            if (up.files.length > <cfoutput>#mnum#</cfoutput>) {
                up.removeFile(file);
                }
            });
            if (up.files.length >= <cfoutput>#mnum#</cfoutput>) {
                $('#pickfiles').hide('slow');
            }
        },
        FilesRemoved: function(up, files) {
            if (up.files.length < 1) {
                $('#pickfiles').fadeIn('slow');
            }
        }
    },
    resize : {width : 300, height : 10000, quality : 90}, // forces images to be resized to a width of 300px if wider than 300px
    preinit: attachCallbacks,
    UploadComplete: function(up, file, response) {
        if ($("#result").length > 0){
            $("#results").prepend(info.response);
        } else {
            $("#flash_uploader").after("<div id='results'>"+info.response+"</div>");
        }
    },
    flash_swf_url : '../../js/plupload.flash.swf'
});
});
// Where should we go after upload
function attachCallbacks(Uploader){
    Uploader.bind('FileUploaded', function(Up, File, response){
        function IsJson(response) {
        alert('Response from server: ' + response.file); // for testing only
        counter++
        var newRow = '<tr><td><input type="hidden" name="file_'+counter+'" value="'+response.file+'">'
        newRow += 'Label the file: '+response.file+' <input type="text" name="filename_'+counter+'"></td></tr>'
        $("#detail").append(newRow)
    }});
};
</script>
<div id="results"></div>
<table id="detail">
</table>
<cfif IsDefined('response')><cfdump var="#response#"></cfif>
</body>
</html>
```

This the backend processing page - upload.cfc

```
<cfcomponent>
  <cffunction name="upload" access="remote" returntype="struct" returnformat="json" output="false">
    <cfscript>
      var uploadDir = expandPath('/uploads/'); // should be a temp directory that you clear periodically to flush orphaned files 
      var uploadFile =  uploadDir & arguments.NAME;
      var response = {'result' = arguments.NAME, 'id' = 0};
      var result = {};
    </cfscript>     

    <!--- save file data from multi-part form.FILE --->
    <cffile action="upload" result="result" filefield="FILE" destination="#uploadFile#" nameconflict="overwrite"/>

    <cfscript>
      // Example: you can return uploaded file data to client 
      response['size'] = result.fileSize;
      response['type'] = result.contentType;
      response['saved'] = result.fileWasSaved;
      return response;
    </cfscript>
  </cffunction>
</cfcomponent>
```

You can try the above example here: [url] www.turn2cash.co.uk/plupload/examples/jquery/queue_widget.cfm [/url]

As mentioned above, the script works well with uploading (in this case) upto 6 images as determined by the mnum variable. What I need help with is with how to access the uploaded files (with page refresh) and be able to manipulate them.

I have setup an example (using cffileupload) of what I am after here [url] www turn2cash.co.uk/a/index.cfm [/url] 
Although this works fine, it requires a page refresh, which is what I am trying to avoid.

Please provide any help you can.

Added 7 september 2012

I have tried both methods suggested by Miguel but did not achieve any positive outcomes. They actually caused the UI not to sow at all. However I found this and tried it:

```
preinit: attachCallbacks,
        UploadComplete: function(up, file, response) {
            if ($("#result").length > 0){
                $("#results").prepend(info.response);
            } else {
                $("#flash_uploader").after("<div id='results'>"+info.response+"</div>");
            }
        },
        flash_swf_url : '../../js/plupload.flash.swf'
    });
});
// Where should we go after upload
function attachCallbacks(Uploader){
    Uploader.bind('FileUploaded', function(Up, File, Response){
        alert('Response from server: ' + Response.response);
});
};
</script>
```

I now get an alert displaying:

```
Response from server: {"saved":true,"result":"home.png","id":"0","size":"5988","type":"image"}
```

This at least prooves that the cfc script is working and the 'response' varialable is being returned. I still have no idea how to make use of this information as I have no knowledge of jquery, ajax or javascript. Please help if you can.

Comment: What have you done on your end so far? [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com). You should be getting a response back to the browser that you can parse apart, or a notice that the upload has finished so that you can redirect the user to a success page that would then show them information about the files they've uploaded.

Comment: You should be able to simply deserialize the response (it is json) into a JS structure and then output it how you need to. The response of the code you have identified will be in json - it's designed to be called from a page as you describe, but handling a json response is *usually* done on the client side with something like jquery or your favorite js library.

Comment: Your suggestion is what I am trying to do, but don't know how to! Plupload is event driven as their examples show, once it completes all uploads an event is triggered that calls a function to process the response. Please provide an example of how to parse or deserialize the response as I am not sure about json. I have tried adding 'preinit: attachCallbacks' and 
    function attachCallbacks(Uploader){
    Uploader.bind('FileUploaded', function(Up, File, response){
        alert('Server response: '+response.name);                   
      });
    };
as per forum suggestions, but it dosen't work

Comment: Can you please post an example response from "upload.cfcmethod=upload"? Thanks

Comment: The upload.cfc?method=upload works great! The addiditonal code I added as per forum sugestions does not do anything. The files are uploaded successfully and that's it. I need one of pluploads events to trigger a function into action. This is something I don't know how to do.

Comment: Can you post a code example of your Plupload code, and your callback handler?

Comment: Have you tried the jQuery parseJSON method?

Look here: [plupload json response][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8298793/plupload-json-response

Comment: Thank you Miguel, I do not know how to handle json responses, is there any chance of providing an example I could integrate into my code above so that I can see how it works? This will also help me with future work! I really would appreciate this.

Answer (score 0):

The link that I posted before has the example code.  Sorry to post this as an answer but since I have no rep I cannot comment.

I think part of your confusion is in the request processing.  You have this line of code at the bottom of your example.

```
<cfif IsDefined('response')><cfdump var="#response#"></cfif>
```

That will never fire because the coldfusion page is processed before you make the javascript ajax call to the server for the file upload.  You will need to handle the response in javascript.

Are you seeing this alert from the attachCallbacks function?

```
alert('Response from server: ' + response.file); // for testing only
```

Comment: No, there is no response from that alert! I can only assume the code in the cfc doc is working correctly as the file is being uploaded.

Comment: You could send yourself an email or log to a file from you cfc doc to verify it is being called (and also to view the response it is sending back).  I have not used plupload before but have used jquery to make ajax calls.  I know it can be done, just a matter of where to place the code.  Did you look at ColdFusion's builtin function to upload multiple files?  cffile action = "uploadAll" [link is here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7388.html)

Comment: Yes Miguel, I did try that and did setup a system for uploading multiple files successfully. I have a working model here [url] www turn2cash.co.uk/a/index.cfm [/url]. The only problem with this is that it causes page refreshes and that is what I am trying to avoid. Thanks for the suggestion though!

Comment: Okay, you did mention that in your question. I found this similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10313319/not-able-to-get-json-data-from-plupload).  Look at the code example from that post, particularly the uploader.bind section.  It is slightly different than yours.  The answer for their problem was to use $.parseJSON(response.response) instead.

Comment: Another thing I just noticed, in your backend cfc you need to return the response as JSON.  Just having the return type set in the function declaration does not automatically do this for you.  So instead of 'return response;' try 'return SerializeJSON(response);'.  This would explain why you are not seeing the alert fire. You are checking if the response is JSON first and it is not. This may have been your issue all along.  Try this first and see if you get that alert.  If not, then try the other suggestion with the $.parseJSON(response.response).

Comment: I have tried both methods but did not achieve any positive outcomes. They actually caused the UI not to sow at all. However I found this and tried it:

Comment: I didn't know how to reply with a long answer and code here so I have added it to the end of my original post above.

Comment: Alright, cool, looks like you have your JSON response returning.  I guess the question now is what are you trying to do exactly?  Your upload is working and your cfc is returning the info back to you.  You should be able to reference each piece of the returned JSON by first parsing the response as I mentioned before; var newobj = jQuery.parseJSON(Response.response); Then you should be able to reference each piece as newobj.result or newobj.size etc.